# Unable update PLC tag value using Linx OPC server?

Tags: c#, plc

PLC :- Allen-Bradley ,
App :- Linx OPC server
Language :- C#.Net

Working with an emulator in the "Studio 5000 Compact Logics L33ER" of Allen-Bradley PLC.

Unable to update the PLC value through a Linx OPC server using "groupStateWrite/groupWrite", I can read the data from AB PLC but sending value "(write item)" is not working ().

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    #region OPC Privete Fields

    private Server server;
    private OpcCom.Factory fact = new OpcCom.Factory();
    private Subscription groupRead;
    private SubscriptionState groupState;
    private Subscription groupWrite;
    private bool connectStatus;

    #endregion OPC Privete Fields

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool Connect;
        Connect = ConnectOpcServer();
        if (Connect == true)
        {
            tbxConnStatus.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            tbxConnStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
            tbxConnStatus.Text = "Connected :-) .....";

            ReadValue();
        }
        else
        {
            tbxConnStatus.BackColor= System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            tbxConnStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            tbxConnStatus.Text = "Not Connected :-/ ";
        }
    }




    public bool ConnectOpcServer()
    {
        try
        {
            //CONNECT PLC SERVER
            server = new Opc.Da.Server(fact, null);
            server.Url = new Opc.URL("opcda://localhost/RSLinx OPC Server");
            server.Connect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void ReadValue()
    {
        try
        {
            //READ GROUP SUBSCRIPTION
            groupState = new Opc.Da.SubscriptionState();
            groupState.Name = "New2";
            groupState.UpdateRate = 1000;
            groupState.Active = true;

            //READ GROUP CREATION
            groupRead = (Opc.Da.Subscription)server.CreateSubscription(groupState);
            Opc.Da.Item[] items = new Opc.Da.Item[1];

            //REPORT_DTS - TRIGGER
            items[0] = new Opc.Da.Item();
            items[0].ItemName = "[MYPLC]RT_BOOL";

            items = groupRead.AddItems(items);
            Opc.Da.ItemValueResult[] values = groupRead.Read(items);

            //ADD TRIGGER VALUES
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(values[0].Value.ToString()))
            {
                tbxReadValue.Text = values[0].Value.ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //WRITE ITEM
            SubscriptionState groupStateWrite = new Opc.Da.SubscriptionState();
            groupStateWrite = new Opc.Da.SubscriptionState();
            groupStateWrite.Name = "GroupWrite";
            groupStateWrite.Active = true;
            groupWrite = (Opc.Da.Subscription)server.CreateSubscription(groupStateWrite);

            //CREATE THE ITEM TO WRITE
            Opc.Da.Item[] itemtoadd = new Opc.Da.Item[1];
            itemtoadd[0] = new Opc.Da.Item();
            itemtoadd[0].ItemName = "[MYPLC]RT_BOOL";

            //CREATE THE ITEM THAT CONTAINS THE VALUE TO WRITE
            Opc.Da.ItemValue[] writevalues = new Opc.Da.ItemValue[1];
            writevalues[0] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue(itemtoadd[0]);    -->I need to send or update the value from 1 to 0

            groupWrite.AddItems(itemtoadd);
            writevalues[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(tbxWriteValue.Text.ToString());
            groupWrite.Write(writevalues);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```